# Weird behavior accessing Profile2 field

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm using [Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-7.0) with the [Profile 2 Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2). I have some custom fields which are all working well, for the most part.

I have a `hook_user_update()` function in my module, where I want to take action based on the value of a Profile2 field. I'm testing this as an administrative user editing the user profile and saving.

The hook function contains the following:

```
var_dump($info[$role]->$field);
```

And outputs this:

```
array(1) {
  ["und"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(16) "/producer/my-biz"
      ["format"]=>
      NULL
      ["safe_value"]=>
      string(16) "/producer/my-biz"
    }
  }
}
```

...which is correct. So, I should easily be able to get the value (or `safe_value`).

But when I do this:

```
var_dump($info[$role]->$field['und'][0]['value']);
```

I get this:

> Fatal error:  Cannot use string offset as an array in /<...>/sites/all/modules/ssvalidate/ssvalidate.module on line 155*

When I do this:

```
var_dump($info[$role]->$field['und']);
```

I get this:

> NULL

How can this be? When I view the entire field array, it has everything in it. As soon as I try accessing the elements of that (nested) array, things go haywire.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be going on?

Comment: When using a variable as a PHP object key, try wrapping it in brackets: {}

.i.e. $info[$role]->{$field}['und'][0]['value']